# select query to display result and the parameter that got the result when using OR clause in where (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query

```
select columnX from tableA
  where (columnY like '%string1%' or columnY like '%string2%');
```

but I also want to know what parameter (string1 or string2) got matched because of which I got my result, so I modify my query to

```
  select columnX value,'string1' pattern from tableA
  where columnY like '%string1%'
  union
  select columnX,'string2' from tableA
  where columnY like '%string2%'
```

This gives me my result but makes the query huge (as I have hundreds of patterns to match against so basically I write the entire query for each parameter), I highly doubt this would be the best way to do this, is there some other way to do this where I do not have to write a new query for all the patterns that I want to match ?
Can this be done by simply modifying the query or will I have to use any advanced construct of Oracle SQL to perform what I need ?

Comment: Your re-write is not equivalent to the original. In the original you get a single row in the output if either `string1` or `string2` or **both** are matched. In the re-write you get two rows if both strings are matched. Which is the desired result?

Comment: Ideally the result that I want is to have columnX, and all the patterns that got matched with the particular columnX.
eg a result like this is ideal for me:
ColumnX, pattern
"value1" , "string1,string2"
"value2" , "foo"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget the requirement that there are hundreds of patterns to match.  The solutions using case statements are then impractical I'm afraid as you would have to edit hundreds of those.  Put the compare strings in a table.  Here I simulate that by using a CTE (the compare_strings table).  If you ever need to add a value to compare to, you just add it to the compare_strings table and the query does not have to change.  To simulate, edit the 'efs' to be 'blah' and you will then pick up row 1.

There is a caveat though, as per your example the compare string will match anywhere it appears in columnY, even if the string is embedded within another word that may not be what you want to match on.  To get more precise, you may need to switch to using regexp_like where you can tailor the regex to meet your needs.

```
SQL> WITH tableA(columnX, columnY) AS (
     SELECT 1, 'blah blah blah'  FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 2, 'string2'         FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 3, 'string'          FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 4, 'string1'         FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 5, 'string1 string2' FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 6, NULL              FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 7, 'string3'         FROM DUAL
   ),
   COMPARE_STRINGS(description) AS (
     SELECT 'string1'    FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'efs'        FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'string2'    FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'Mata Hairy' FROM DUAL UNION
     SELECT 'string3'    FROM DUAL
   )
   SELECT columnX, cs.description "hit string"
   FROM TABLEA A CROSS JOIN COMPARE_STRINGS CS
   WHERE a.columnY LIKE '%' || cs.description || '%'
   ORDER BY columnX;

   COLUMNX hit string
---------- ----------
         2 string2
         4 string1
         5 string1
         5 string2
         7 string3
```

Note you get 2 hits in line 5 as columnY contains 2 entries from the compare_strings table.  You'll need to decide how you want to handle that.  See the caveat above.

EDIT 7/10/17 to put multiple hit strings per row on a single line.

Alter the query to use LISTAGG():

```
   SELECT columnX, 
   LISTAGG(cs.description, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY columnX) hit_string
   FROM TABLEA A CROSS JOIN COMPARE_STRINGS CS
   WHERE a.columnY LIKE '%' || cs.description || '%'
   GROUP BY columnX;

SQL> /

   COLUMNX HIT_STRING
---------- --------------------
         2 string2
         4 string1
         5 string1|string2
         7 string3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for.
Is there a way that this can be modified to have all the hit strings for a column in a single row separated by some delimiter ?

Comment: Updated post to show how LISTAGG can achieve this.  I'm saving this in my folder of SQL tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a new column with that logic:

```
    CASE WHEN columnY like '%string1%' THEN 'string1'
         WHEN columnY like '%string2%' THEN 'string2'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columnX,
CASE
    WHEN columnY like '%string1%' THEN 'string1'
    WHEN columnY like '%string2%' THEN 'string2'
    ELSE NULL
END AS pattern
FROM tableA
WHERE (columnY like '%string1%' or columnY like '%string2%');
```

Edit: you can also use `ISNULL('string1','value you want')` if value of 'string1' and 'string2' can possibly be null

Answer (score 0):

```
with tableA as(
    select 'asd' columnY  from dual union all
    select 'string2' columnY  from dual union all
    select 'string' columnY  from dual union all
    select 'string1' columnY  from dual union all
    select 'string1 string2' columnY  from dual  
)

select * from (
    select tableA.*,  
    case when columnY like '%string1%' then 1 else 0 end+
    case when columnY like '%string2%' then 2 else 0 end as res
    from tableA
) t
where res > 0
```

If `res` column is 1, means that `columnY` contains only 'string1', if `res` is 2, this means that contains only 'string2', and if `res` is 3, then `columnY` contains both 'string1' and 'string2'